# Eu quero utilizar CardView para deixar a tela mais bonita só que o cardView funciona semelhante a uma listView?

Tags: java, android

E eu quero pegar dados dinâmicos para mostrar na tela. Dados dinâmicos que virão de uma webservice.

Então, eu preciso utilizar RecyclerView com CardView Layout para tornar os dados dinâmicos?

Como posso tornar meu CardView como se fosse elementos de uma ListView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, depois que o projeto for criado, vá até o arquivo `build.gradle (app)` e adicione as seguintes dependências:

```
compile ‘com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+’
compile ‘com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+’
```

Depois na sua lista existe um item, que provavelmente é definido no seu *adapter*. O exemplo de código a seguir mostra como incluir um *widget* `CardView` no *layout*:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ... >
    <!-- Um CardView com um TextView dentro -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Veja mais detalhes na documentação em [**como criar listas e cartões**](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=pt-br).

Comment: Oi Ack, entãquando vc se refere a lista vc quis dizer a ListView ou recyclerview?

Comment: Qual quer um dos dois, o que você está usando no momento. Para melhor adaptar ao seu cenário, seria bom você adicionar seu código.

Comment: Acho que eu entendi...Eu tenho uma listView e cada elemento da lista eu sou direcionada para uma tela e a partir daí eu posso fazer alguma modificação...eu queria que no meu ListView tivesse o estilo do CardView...

Comment: eu tenho um layout que tem dois textView e esses elemesos sao mostrados em cada elemento da lista... e fiz inflate com o layout da listview

Comment: vou modificar e mostro aqui...

Comment: @Aline É fácil! Cada item do seu projeto tem um layout. Cada pessoa coloca o nome que achar melhor, exemplo: `row.xml`, `item.xml`, `meu_item.xlm`, `item_list.xml`. Esse mesmo layout que possui o textView você vai alterar e colocar o cardview. Ai você insere os dois TextView dentro do cardView e mata a charada.

Comment: Foi isso aí que eu pensei

Comment: Espera eu preciso colocar o xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" em todos os meus Linear layout alem de dentro do cardView? Porque eu tenho um textview que fica dentro de dois LinearLayout

Comment: @Aline Veja a alteração.

Comment: @Aline deixando apenas no LinearLayout, já resolve o problema

Comment: Não deu certo nao. Eu precisava mostrar 10 itens de uma lista, só que apareceram somente 8 elementos.

Comment: @Aline o problema ai já nao é o CardView entende?! Essa resposta atende muito bem o que você quer. Sugiro então fazer uma outra pergunta, para saber porque não está listando esses 10 itens. Você puxa de onde esses itens. Se realmente for fazer outra pergunta, tente detalhar melhor seu problema, inserindo parte do seu código.

Comment: Consertei. Valeu deu tudo certo!

Comment: @Aline =) É isso ae! o/